# JavaScript/Typescript chainable function without class

Tags: javascript, typescript, chaining, chainable

I am trying to correctly code my chainable function in Typescript. Below is the code

```
  const sum = (val: number | undefined) => {
    let internal = Number(val);
    if (val) {
      return function sumup(_val: number | undefined) {
        if (_val && internal !== undefined) {
          internal += _val;
          return sumup;
        }
        return internal;
      };
    }
    return internal;
  };

  console.log('sum:', sum(1)(2)(3)());
```

The function is working to the point that I get the correct result. However, it is yielding a typescript error: `This expression is not callable. Not all constituents of type 'number | ((_val: number | undefined) => number | ...)' are callable. Type 'number' has no call signatures.`

How would I correctly code such a `sum` function without using `class` or `this`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by describing precisely the functions behaviors with [function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads):

```
function sum(): number
function sum(val: number): typeof sum
function sum(val?: number): number | typeof sum {
  let internal = Number(val);
  if (val) {
    function sumup(): number
    function sumup(_val: number): typeof sumup
    function sumup(_val?: number): number | typeof sumup {
      if (_val && internal !== undefined) {
        internal += _val;
        return sumup;
      }
      return internal;
    };
    return sumup;
  }
  return internal;
};

console.log('sum:', sum(1)(2)(3)());
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/fr/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZxAWwBQEoBcizoBGApgE4BQoksCK6GAbgIYA2eBaJpuiUAngAdicYHTSVw0eElSZmLAPzsiZHhy6IAPr0HDRsxAG9yiRC2JREMMFDJhWiALyIAcitKNWWANwmrozxYsIz9TKilaWRABbGVOMlDEcJoZdGiMAH15OK4efiERMWjE5OkimKzWJXx3NXctHQL9NIEQ03b-REz5RAAyXqsbOwcAQkdncAATYmBrYkng4w6O61tSexZEAGpnSpZfZfbSCxB18oPlgF9E02OoU6RV4f3Ey4vbk7OogQvrj-uzk91qxfG9yOQIAhkHBzAA6FhwADmGAA5LIcCiADRiDAARiwGAATASAMwErA+IA)